# read QR Code from IMAGE using xamarin forms for both Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin

I already try following code but getting null, I am using zxing nuget package

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();

var barCodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

var luminanceSource = new RGBLuminanceSource(ImageData, 10, 10);
HybridBinarizer hb = new HybridBinarizer(luminanceSource);
var a = hb.createBinarizer(luminanceSource);
BinaryBitmap bBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(a);

MultiFormatReader multiFormatReader = new MultiFormatReader();
Result result = null;
result = multiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bBitmap);

string rf = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
```

Comment: You could install the plugin
ZXing.Net.Mobile from nuget . Check https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

Comment: We already install and barcode scanner is working fine in my apps, only issue with barcode read from IMAGE file

Comment: @LucasZhang ZXing.Net.Mobile doesn't work on ios